# Are there any downsides to running ubuntu from a external ssd

Tags: dual-boot, usb, ssd

I have a 250GB M.2 NVMe SSD to spare which I would like to install Ubuntu on.

I was thinking about buying an external housing for the SSD, to have a portable Ubuntu installation which I can just plug and play in any PC I might need to do something. I am well aware I will lose performance from the SSD, as USB 3.0 is going to be a massive bottleneck.

Does someone have any experience with running Ubuntu in this configuration? What are the downsides? Will everything work as expected? (plug and play) Would I be better of just plugging the M.2 in the motherboard of my pc?

I'd like to get some feedback from the professionals before making the purchase.

Comment: It should work, but not every PC will play nice with Ubuntu first time without tinkering.  Some will.  Once booted up and running, speed difference will not be too bad unless you are running heavy programs with a lot of read and writes.

Comment: I have a similar setup for my NAS with Debian. That works just fine and is pretty fast, as most things will be loaded into RAM anyways I guess.

Comment: Makes sense, but should it be ran from the m.2 or should I just get a thumb drive for it? as the price for the external housing would be the same.

Comment: m.2 would be more reliable long term.  Depends on how much you expect to use it.  Thumb drive with important data should be backup more often.

Comment: Thanks @crip659. Would there be any benefit on getting a usb type C enclosure or would a usb 3.0 be good enough?

Comment: Depending on your PCs, usb 3.0 ports might be more available, also can be used on usb 2 ports only PCs, if you want it to as portable as possible.  Other than that, don't think a person would notice much of a difference without running tests.

Comment: Think for speed usb 3.1 and usb type c are almost the same, with usb 3.0 a bit slower.